# one.ubuntu.com won't let me upload a large file (using firefox)

Tags: ubuntu-one

I am trying to upload a 4.4GB file to my one.ubuntu.com account. I have a 25GB account and am currently using only 350MB. When I click on the file I want to upload it says it's uploading. When I open up the terminal and type in bmon it shows nothing happening. Bmon is working because I tested it by uploading and downloading from other sites and it registers transmission rates. I first tried uploading this file yesterday and came back hours later and it was still saying 'uploading'. That's when I opened up bmon and saw that nothing was happening. I tried checking publish file and then unchecking it. Didn't matter. I am using Firefox on Linux Mint 14.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Some information elsewhere suggests that Firefox might have a 2Gb limit for POST. It might mean that it's causing a javascript error which is going unnoticed. Could you try with Chrome and let us know if that works for you?

Comment: Chrome works! The file is uploading. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please accept this answer if it was the correct one! Users of this site need to see which answers were "good".